# Is there a OS X equivalent for iproute2?

Tags: command-line, network

I am searching a command line tool collection like iproute2 on Linux.

Network Utility is OK, but I would like it on the command line.

Comment: Explaining what you are trying to accomplish might result in more and better responses.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

iproute2mac
https://github.com/brona/iproute2mac

is available on brew so far

Answer (score 5):

Different users use commands differently, so without knowing how YOU use this utility, it is a difficult question to answer correctly. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2), iproute2 is a single piece of software designed to replace the entire suite of network tools. Chances are there is only one utility that does precisely this, and that is iproute2, which is open source software, so the [source](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2) is available for download, and you can do almost anything you wish with it, such as modify it so that it can be compiled for OS X. But that might be a lot of work... it might not, but it might, so I will give you some more suggestions that you may not have heard before.

### [networksetup](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/networksetup.8.html)

The networksetup command is used to configure network settings typically configured in the System Preferences application. The networksetup command lets you view all types of network parameters, including IP addresses, available network interfaces, and dozens of other variables. Besides its man page I linked to above, I found examples of its use [here](http://itsecureadmin.com/2012/12/configure-mac-osx-network-interface-from-the-command-line/).

---

### MacPorts

I recommend you install macports and search the available software it provides for network utilities until you find what you like.

Installing [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) is simple enough, once xcode (for Mavericks 10.9 [xcode_5.1.1.dmg](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/xcode_5.1.1/xcode_5.1.1.dmg)) is installed:

```
 curl -Ok https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.2.1.tar.bz2
 tar xf MacPorts-2.2.1.tar.bz2
 cd MacPorts-2.2.1
 ./configure
 make
 sudo make install #not war!
 cd ..
 rm -rf Macports-*
 sudo /opt/local/bin/port -v selfupdate
 export PATH=$HOME/macports/bin:$HOME/macports/sbin:$PATH
 export MANPATH=$HOME/macports/share/man:$MANPATH
 diskutil quiet repairPermissions /
```

[MacPorts](http://guide.macports.org/) is worth getting to know as it is a mature package manager for OS X that maintains thousands of open source software commands, utilities, and applications.

I just ran a search on macports for the word "network":

```
 port search network
```

and macports returned 278 ports, and the list includes such powerful tools as [netcat](http://nc110.sourceforge.net/), [nmap](http://nmap.org/), and [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/), and many many more.